# How to get the real CaptureElement size?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using `CaptureElement` to display the output of the camera.

Depending on how the user resizes the window, there can be black borders on either left/right or top/bottom of the camera output.

[image]

I'd like to get the size of the camera output WITHOUT including the black borders. I've tried many height/width/size fields that `CaptureElement` has, including `ActualWidth`, `RenderSize.Width` etc. but none of them returns the real width/height of the camera.

If the black border is of width `100px`, the actual camera output of width `300px`, the width fields will return `2*100px+300px = 500px`. They all include the black border.

How do I get only the width and height of the actual camera display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Sunteen's answer to get the resolution of the camera. Then, I calculated both the camera resolution ratio and the video preview output ratio. Using this information, I could calculate the actual size of the video output.

Here's the solution.

```
var props = (VideoEncodingProperties) _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController
    .GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);

double cameraWidth = props.Width;
double cameraHeight = props.Height;

double previewOutputWidth = CameraPreview.ActualWidth;
double previewOutputHeight =  CameraPreview.ActualHeight;

double cameraRatio = cameraWidth / cameraHeight;
double previewOutputRatio = previewOutputWidth / previewOutputHeight;

double actualWidth = (cameraRatio <= previewOutputRatio) ? 
    previewOutputHeight * cameraRatio
    : previewOutputWidth;
double actualHeight = (cameraRatio <= previewOutputRatio) ? 
    previewOutputHeight
    : previewOutputWidth / cameraRatio;
```

Comment: The helper class I provided just has the `AspectRatio` you could check.

Comment: Sunteen: I thank you for your answer, I've upvoted it. But you don't provide a complete solution, only a partial one. There's also code that's not relevant. I will accept your answer if you edit your answer to fix these two things.

Comment: Never mind, you could mark yourself to end up this thread. The helper class is more common using for these similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get only the width and height of the actual camera display?

You could use the [`IMediaEncodingProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.MediaProperties.IMediaEncodingProperties) interface to get the width and height of the camera preview stream, and make the `CaptureElement` control same size with the stream or even you can set the stream size to the `CaptureElement`. In that cases you may not see the black parts. For example:

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="myCaptureElement"  />
<Button Click="Button_Click">Click me to see a preview</Button>
```

Code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{ 
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Using Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture APIs 
            // to stream from webcam
            MediaCapture mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
            await mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
            MediaStreamType streamType = MediaStreamType.VideoPreview;
            // Query all properties of the specified stream type
            IEnumerable<StreamPropertiesHelper> allVideoProperties =
                 mediaCaptureMgr.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(streamType).Select(x => new StreamPropertiesHelper(x));
            // Query the current preview settings
            StreamPropertiesHelper previewProperties = new StreamPropertiesHelper(mediaCaptureMgr.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview));
            myCaptureElement.Height = previewProperties.Height;
            myCaptureElement.Width = previewProperties.Width;
            // Start capture preview.                
            myCaptureElement.Source = mediaCaptureMgr;
            await mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
}
class StreamPropertiesHelper
{
    private IMediaEncodingProperties _properties;

    public StreamPropertiesHelper(IMediaEncodingProperties properties)
    {
        if (properties == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(properties));
        }

        // This helper class only uses VideoEncodingProperties or VideoEncodingProperties
        if (!(properties is ImageEncodingProperties) && !(properties is VideoEncodingProperties))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument is of the wrong type. Required: " + typeof(ImageEncodingProperties).Name
                + " or " + typeof(VideoEncodingProperties).Name + ".", nameof(properties));
        }

        // Store the actual instance of the IMediaEncodingProperties for setting them later
        _properties = properties;
    }

    public uint Width
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as ImageEncodingProperties).Width;
            }
            else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Width;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public uint Height
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as ImageEncodingProperties).Height;
            }
            else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).Height;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public uint FrameRate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
            {
                if ((_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator != 0)
                {
                    return (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Numerator /
                        (_properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return Math.Round((Height != 0) ? (Width / (double)Height) : double.NaN, 2); }
    }

    public IMediaEncodingProperties EncodingProperties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
    }

    public string GetFriendlyName(bool showFrameRate = true)
    {
        if (_properties is ImageEncodingProperties ||
            !showFrameRate)
        {
            return Width + "x" + Height + " [" + AspectRatio + "] " + _properties.Subtype;
        }
        else if (_properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
        {
            return Width + "x" + Height + " [" + AspectRatio + "] " + FrameRate + "FPS " + _properties.Subtype;
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

}
```

The above code snippet are referenced [Set format, resolution, and frame rate for MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/set-media-encoding-properties), more details you also can reference [`CameraResolution`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) official sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using this I apparently get only the actual camera resolution (in my case 640 x 480) - not the kind of resolution that the camera preview displays in any given moment. Since the user can resize the window, the camera preview shrinks/expands. I'd like to get out the actual width/height of the camera preview output.